# JavaScript - All onClick events are not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alright, so I'm making a Facebook-style chat. But that doesn't really matter.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SkHme/7/

Nice and pretty, right? Well, there's a problem. Notice this line:

```
<div class="conversation EmperorCuzco" onclick="setActive('EmperorCuzco')">
```

See the `onclick` attribute? Well, it's not working. However, I have confirmed that the function itself DOES work. (if you run it just like that in the JavaScript, it runs like a dream) I have further confirmed that the function is not the problem by attempting to replace the `onclick` value with a simple `alert('blah')`, but that doesn't work either.

So, what's up? I'm guessing that something in my JavaScript is somehow disabling something, but I have absolutely no idea what it could be, nor how I could go about fixing it. I did some web searching, but couldn't find anything that helps.

What's going on?

Comment: Looks like some event handler in jquery is trying to ajax to a resource that doesn't exist (load.php)

Comment: Maybe there is an error somewhere in the file that causes a compilation problem, this will stop code from running.  Do you see any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: The AJAX problem isn't doing it--I have that file locally, just not on jsFiddle. :)

Comment: You try putting a semi-colon after your javascript call? `setActive('EmperorCuzco');`

Comment: Yeah. I updated the link in my question with that in mind, and also the function fix mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `setActive` function is defined *inside the scope* of the `$(document).ready` handler. Move the function outside that function so that it is in the global scope.

Right now it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // ...
    function setActive(new_conversation)
    {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Now change that to:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // ...
});

function setActive(new_conversation)
{
    // ...
}
```

Really though, you should separate your content from your interactions and bind those event handlers in your script itself. Something like:

```
// Refers to the last clicked conversation *button*
// Initialize to empty jQuery object
var $active_conversation = $([]);

// Binding on #chat, targeting click events on .conversation_button children
$("#chat").on("click", ".conversation_button", function() {
    // Hide currently active conversation
    $active_conversation.hide();
    $active_conversation.siblings('.conversation_button').removeClass("selected");

    // Set as currently active conversation button
    // Note: this refers to the clicked <div class="conversation_button">
    var $this = $(this);
    $active_conversation = $this.siblings('.conversation');

    // Show this conversation
    $active_conversation.show();
    $this.removeClass("alert").addClass("selected");
});
```

Some advantages of this approach:

- You don't need different classes for different conversations. By storing the actual conversation DOM element (as a jQuery object) in `$active_conversation`, the conversation can be identified without any extra processing.
- You can add and remove whole list items with a `conversation` without assigning new event handlers. In the sample above, the event handler for *all* `.conversation_button` elements is defined at the level of `#chat`. For more about this binding mechanism, read up on [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for pre-1.7).

Here, have an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/9ptFh/)! :-)

Comment: Or use jQuery to bind the events instead of using inline click handlers.

Comment: Ahhh, beautiful. :) This looks much nicer, and the comments really help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, the reason why your updated fiddle didn't work is because the handler should be defined on the `conversation_button` elements instead of on the `conversation` elements. The `conversation` elements are the ones being hidden - you can't actually click those when they're hidden, right? ;-)

Comment: I would still have the click event call `setActive` rather than move all the code to the click event.  You may want to set a conversation to active when a message is received, or set the active conversation to inactive when you click on it.  Tightly coupling events with actions makes this difficult.

Comment: @BrianNickel Good point, but then you should pass the conversation as a DOM element or a jQuery object. Then, you can change the event handler to call `setActive(this.siblings(".conversation"))`. Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/9ptFh/2/) with that change.

Comment: I always call the argument `selector` or in this case maybe `conversationSelector`.  The first line of the function is always something like: `var $conversation = $(conversationSelector);`.  Then you can pass a jQuery object, a DOM element, or a selector string with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If all you say is really true (bad mistakes happen), the only thing that can make this is that an other event handler which takes your event before uses `stopPropagation()` or `return false;`

A quick check that can do is replace `onclick` with `onmousedown` or `onmouseup`, and see if you alert become visible.

Comment: Of course what I'm saying is true. :P I attempted other events, and they did not fix it either, unfortunately.